# Prove that n^(n/2) < n!, n>=2.

Tags: inequality

I am trying to prove that 
$$n^{n/2}<n!,\text{ for } n\ge2.$$
I can't really figure it out.

Comment: BTW, this is not true for $n=2$.

Comment: Hint: Show that $n!^2\geq n^n$. Re-arrange the products of $n!^2$ so that you get $n$ terms greater than  or equal to $n$.

Comment: Thank you for your help, managed  to prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity assume $n$ is even. The same method works for odd $n$ with a little tinkering.

$n! = n(n-1)(n-2) \cdot \ldots 2 \cdot 1$

Pair up the outermost terms, then the next outermost and so on. We get

$n! = (n \cdot 1) \cdot 2(n-1) \cdot 3(n-2) \cdot \ldots$

There are $n/2$ terms. Each term looks like $k(n-k+1)$ which is at least $n$ (why?)

So $n!$ is at least equal to the product of $n/2$ copies of $n$.

In other words $n! \ge n^{n/2}$

Answer (score 1):

Note that if we have $ 1\le k\le n$, for integer $k,n$ , we can write:
$$
\begin{aligned}
0\lt n+\frac{1}{2}-k &\le n - \frac{1}{2} \\
\left(n+\frac{1}{2}-k\right)^2 &\le \left(n - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \\
k\cdot(2n-k+1)&\ge2n
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore
$$
(2n)! = 1\cdot2\cdots 2n = \prod_{k=1}^{n} {k\cdot(2n-k+1)} \ge (2n)^n
$$